# Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected on kotlin and firebase

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a little problem I get this message on the 3rd line:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

```
 if(task.isComplete){
    val user:FirebaseUser?=auth.currentUser
    verifyEmail(user)

    val userBD=dbReference.child(user?.uid)

    userBD.child("Name").setValue(name)
    userBD.child("lastName").setValue(lastname)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that `user` has a value, you can hard-cast it with:

```
val userBD=dbReference.child((user as User).uid)
```

The `user as User` converts the `User?` to a `User`, that you can then call `uid` on. But if `user` is `null`, the above will crash.

---

If you are not certain, it's better to perform a check:

```
if (user is User) {
  val userBD=dbReference.child(user.uid)

  userBD.child("Name").setValue(name)
  userBD.child("lastName").setValue(lastname)
}
```

The `if (user is User) {` check converts the `User?` to a `User`, which you can then call `uid` on.